# utf-8 url parsing in php:file_get_content and browser

Tags: php, file-get-contents, url-parsing

I want to get a a URL content using `file_get_contents($url);` when I copy the URL from browser address bar it is like this:

```
  $url="http://www.mashadhome.com/fa-estate-39855-tags-%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B4-%D8%A2%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A8%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1%20%D8%B5%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AF%20%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C";
```

but when I automatic get the url using

```
$homepage1 = file_get_contents($url_value);
$doc1 = new DOMDocument;
$doc1->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
@$doc1->loadHTML($homepage1);
$xpath1 = new DOMXpath($doc1);

$nodes1 = $xpath1->query("//html/body/section/div/div/section/figure/a");
$href = $node1->getAttribute('href');
```

it is sothing like this:

```
$href="http://www.mashadhome.com/fa-estate-39855-tags-فروش-آپارتمان-بلوار صیاد شیرازی";
```

I use code like above to get content of this link, but the `file_get_contents($href)` don't work for second URL, either when I copy second address to browser it works good;

so question is this: why second address doesn't work? how to convert first address to second type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url can accept restricted character set, namely ASCII letter, digits, hyphen. To access such url, it needs to be encoded to the format accepted by your server, like in your first example. Have a look at [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

Of course you need to use urlencode only on parts that are not url special characters (like `:`, `/`). In this instance, you would use urlencode on the `fa-estate-39855-tags-فروش-آپارتمان-بلوار صیاد شیرازی` part only.

Comment: Thanks @Ram Sharma it was good guide, but in my case rawurlencode() worked, because in my url space is a common character, and it seems urlencode() can't support it.